# VB.NET Formatting numbers according culture selected

Tags: vb.net, globalization, cultureinfo, culture

I have a multilanguage vb.net app.

I am trying to format a number (ULong) to display it according to current language currency group separator by doing this:

```
value.ToString("0.##", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

CultrueInfo.CurrentCulture can be english (en-GB), spanish (es-ES) or catalan (ca-ES) depending on the language selected in the app.

The problem is the following:

1. If spanish (es-ES) is selected then value is not correctly
   formatted as spanish language currency group separator is `','`
   instead of `'.'` indicated in `"0.##"` so I need to put `"0,##"` instead.

for example 1200 is formated as is 1200 instead of 1.200

2. But if I change mask to `"0,##"` then if language is set to en-GB,
   value is not formatted correctly as currency group separator for it
   is `"."` instead of `","` indicated in `"0,##"` so I need to put `"0.##"`
   instead.

So how to adapt mask automatically to work for all languages? detecting language and set the correct mask accordingly? but it is ok for a few language but not suitable for a lot of languages...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is you're hardcoding the radix point (`,` or `.` character).

Use a Standard Formatting String instead. See here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

> `N` - Number - Integral and decimal digits, group separators, and a decimal separator with optional negative sign.

The `N{n}` format uses "Number" formatting and an integer following that is the number of places after the radix point:

```
value.ToString("N2", CultureInfo.CurrentCulture)
```

Comment: It is an Ulong so probably  it is N0